# Kotlin and generics confusion

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, kotlin-generics

I have some `Drawers` with generics:

```
abstract class BaseGeoDrawer<KEY : Any, GEO : Any, ITEM : Any>

abstract class BasePolygonDrawer<KEY : Any, ITEM : Any>: BaseGeoDrawer<KEY, Polygon, ITEM>
class TeamAreaDrawer : BasePolygonDrawer<String, Team>

abstract class BaseMarkerDrawer<KEY : Any, ITEM : Any> : BaseGeoDrawer<KEY, Marker, ITEM>
class TeamPositionDrawer : BaseMarkerDrawer<String, Team>
```

Then I have a `controller` that accept these `Drawers`, putting them in a `ArrayList`

```
private val drawers = ArrayList<BaseGeoDrawer<Any, Any, Any>>()
open fun addGeoDrawer(drawer: BaseGeoDrawer<Any, Any, Any>) {
    drawers.add(drawer)
}
```

And later on calling methods in these `Drawers`

```
//Method in controller
private fun onMarkerClicked(marker: Marker): Boolean {
    return drawers.any { it.onGeoClicked(marker) }
}

//Method in BaseGeoDrawer
fun onGeoClicked(geo: GEO): Boolean
```

The problem appear on this line

```
teamAreaDrawer = TeamAreaDrawer(this)
mapController.addGeoDrawer(teamAreaDrawer)
```

Android Studio will not allow it, telling me

```
Type mismatch.
Required: BaseGeoDrawer<Any, Any, Any>
Found: TeamAreaDrawer
```

I tried using out for `drawers`

```
private val drawers = ArrayList<BaseGeoDrawer<out Any, out Any, out Any>>()
```

But then `onMarkerClicked` will not compile, with the following error

```
Out-projected type BaseGeoDrawer<out Any, out Any, out Any> prohibits the use of 'public final fun onGeoClicked(geo: GEO) defined in mypackage.BaseGeoDrawer'
```

Comment: Does that last error literally end on "..."?

Comment: No, it's the method's name onGeoClicked

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you need `GEO` as a **contravariant** type parameter in `BaseGeoDrawer` to use `onGeoClicked(GEO)` but `ArrayList<BaseGeoDrawer<Any, Any, Any>>` is **invariant** in its type. This means that you can't add anything else than a `BaseGeoDrawer<Any, Any, Any>`. If you try to use the types of `BaseGeoDrawer` as **covariant** it will not compile because you need it as **contravariant** when you call `onGeoClicked(GEO)`.

Considering that until now in Kotlin a type parameter can't be **bivariant**, the only way to do it, is to do an unchecked cast.

In this specific case, you can do:

```
val teamAreaDrawer = TeamAreaDrawer(this) as BaseGeoDrawer<Any, Any, Any>
mapController.addGeoDrawer(teamAreaDrawer)
```

If you think about it, in Java, you would have done the same, because you would have had:

```
List<BaseGeoDrawer> drawers = new ArrayList<>();

public void example() {
    TeamAreaDrawer teamAreaDrawer = new TeamAreaDrawer();
    drawers.add(teamAreaDrawer);
    // This is an unchecked cast.
    drawers.get(0).onGeoClicked("Example");
}
```

I recommend you to read more about variance [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).